# ng-view is not working on AngularJS but others is working

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, razor

I new to AngularJS, I working on it using Visual Studio 2022 Preview and Razor.

I downloaded and added this three files, this way

```
<script src="~/angular-1.8.2/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="~/angular-1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/angular-1.8.2/angular.js"></script>
```

Everything is working good but route is not showing!

```
var ThePrinter = angular.module('Mine', ['ntRoute']);
    ThePrinter.config(function($routeProvider)
    {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            template:'<h1>Maganes Pro</h1>'
        });
    });
```

Heres my csHtml Page

```
<body ng-app="Mine">
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">MyAngular</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="container" ng-controller="MyCont">
    <div ng-view>

    </div>

    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>

<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        &copy; 2023 - MyAngular - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
    
</footer>

<script src="~/angular-1.8.2/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="~/angular-1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/angular-1.8.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

<script>
    var ThePrinter = angular.module('Mine', ['ntRoute']);
    ThePrinter.config(function($routeProvider)
    {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            template:'<h1>Maganes Pro</h1>'
        });
    });
    var Mine = angular.module("Mine", []);
    Mine.factory('MyFactory', function () {
        return {
            user:'Magnos',
            pass:'018',
            MyFun: function () { console.log('fine'); }
        };
    });
    Mine.controller("MyCont", function ($scope, $http, MyFactory){
        $http.get('Index').then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });

        $http.post('Index', { Magnos: 'Maganes', Pass: 100 }).then(function (arr) {
            console.log(arr);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
        $scope.Myhtml = '<p>Mine</p>'
        $scope.myfac = MyFactory.user;
        $scope.myfacpass = MyFactory.pass;
        $scope.MyFunction = MyFactory.MyFun();

        var MyDate = new Date();
        $scope.hideorshow = function () {
            $scope.thehide = !$scope.thehide;
        };
        $scope.thehide = true;
        $scope.torf = true;
        $scope.FirstName = 'Micheal';
        $scope.LastName = 'Jackson';
        $scope.Magnos = 'MGS Magnos';
        $scope.MySelect = 'Select';
        $scope.MYCB = 'MYCB';
        $scope.AMagnos = {Name:'Maganes', Bozo:150};
        $scope.data = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
        $scope.data2 = [
            {UN:'Magnos', Pass:018},
            {UN:'Casper', Pass:012}
        ];
        $scope.MyClick = function ()
        {
            alert('Fine');
        };
        $scope.BigArray = [
            { Emp: 'Magnos', Phone: 012, Date: MyDate },
            { Emp: 'Casper', Phone: 011, Date: MyDate },
            { Emp: 'Hunter', Phone: 010, Date: MyDate },
            { Emp: 'Maganes', Phone: 018, Date: MyDate }
        ];
        console.log($scope.Username);
        console.log($scope.Password);
    });
   
</script>
```

Comment: You need a [Route] attribute in the controller on the server.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis

Comment: Can you explain it more for me?

Comment: I using razor, not mvc

Comment: See  : https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp